# Importing a column of data from XML and have it inserted into new column in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I currently manually enter data into spreadsheets in accordance to the following scenario: Servers carry out backups on a daily basis. Each day, the software that conducts the backups also creates a 'Summary Report' of all the backups for all the servers within the past 24 hours. The summary is then emailed to me in an HTML format, however the summary report can also be generated in XML and PDF format if I want. With this summary report, I read through it (daily) and manually enter the backup job status for each server  (Success, Fail, Killed, Delayed, Not Scheduled, Not Run  or No Alert) into our excel spreadsheet which takes the format shown on the following screenshot shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8wzm3aktdbikxn/Capture1.PNG?dl=0).

Sometimes a backup job for a server can be attempted three or four times, however, the outcome of the very last backup attempt is the one that matters to me as this is the one that will go into the spreadsheet.

In an XML format the summary report contains all the possible jobstatus (Success, Fail, Killed, Delayed, Not Scheduled, Not Run and No Alert). If the outcome for server1 is Killed then I will see this in the XML file as **Killed="1"** and the rest will show like this **completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" killed="1" noRun="0" noSchedule="0"**

Ultimately, I am want to try to automate this process - I want the computer to enter the data for me.

So far I have thought of having the Summary Reports generated as an XML file which could then have **only** the **jobstatus** for each server imported into my spreadsheet and placed in a new column to the right with the date at the top (as shown in my screenshot).

The problem I have is that I am not aware if this is possible and assuming that it is possible, I have no idea as to how to go about doing this.

I hope my question is specific enough as I have tried my best - however if anyone wants clarity about anything please let me know.

Below is a sample of the XML Data:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <Rpt_BackupJobSummary>
  <Rpt_Report_TitleInfo reportTitle="Backup Job Summary Report" /> 
  <Rpt_Report_Details ccId="FABE6" csName="bla-bla-bla" time="08/27/2015 16:27:49" version="9.0.0(BUILD84)" /> 
  <Rpt_Report_Criteria agentTypes="All" backupTypes="Full, Incremental, Differential, Synthetic Full" computers="server1, server2, server3, server4, server5, server6, server7, server8, server9, server10, server11, server12, server13, server14, server15, server16, server17, server18, server19, server20, server21, server22, server23, server24, server25, server26" groupBy="Client" include="Failure Reason, Job Description" jobId="All" jobStatus="All" locale="English" storagePolicyNCopy="All" throughput="GB/Hour" timeRange="Show Time In TimeZone: CommServe" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440687602" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="All" killed="0" noRun="221" noSchedule="88" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440604805" totalJobs="221" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608422" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server1" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608422" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608422" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server2" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608422" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440629713" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server3" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440629713" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440615613" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server4" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440615613" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440629715" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server5" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440629715" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440629715" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server6" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440629715" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440687602" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server7" killed="0" noRun="10" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608424" totalJobs="10" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440629711" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server8" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440629711" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440629711" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server9" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440629711" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440687602" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server10" killed="0" noRun="10" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608424" totalJobs="10" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440687602" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server11" killed="0" noRun="7" noSchedule="1" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608413" totalJobs="7" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608421" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server12" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608421" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="0" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server13" killed="0" noRun="0" noSchedule="1" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="0" totalJobs="0" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608422" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server14" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608422" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440622814" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server15" killed="0" noRun="3" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440622811" totalJobs="3" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440615613" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server16" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440615613" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="0" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server18" killed="0" noRun="0" noSchedule="1" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="0" totalJobs="0" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608422" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server19" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608422" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608422" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server20" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608422" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608420" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server21" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608420" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608423" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server22" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608423" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440622814" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server23" killed="0" noRun="2" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440622814" totalJobs="2" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440615612" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server24" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440615612" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="1440608418" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server25" killed="0" noRun="1" noSchedule="0" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="1440608418" totalJobs="1" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" /> 
  <Rpt_BackupSummary backupSize="0" completed="0" completedWithErrors="0" delayed="0" endTime="0" failedFolders="0" failedObjects="0" groupBy="server26" killed="0" noRun="0" noSchedule="1" protectedObjects="0" running="0" startTime="0" totalJobs="0" unCompressedSize="0" unsuccessfull="0" />
```

Comment: This certainly is possible. Excel VBA has the [OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838643.aspx) method that can open a XML into separate workbook. The challenge is complexity of XML file (i.e., very nested/attribute-centric style) Then VLookup or Index/Match can map column values to existing spreadsheet by Server name. Can you post a sample of XML data?

Comment: @Parfait 
Hi, further to your comment, I have added sample XML into my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Try out OpenXML: `Dim wb    Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:="C:\Path\To\XMLfile.xml", LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)`. Your XML sample imports into a workable table. FYI - StackOverflow is not a code scripting service. We help with troubleshooting for coders stuck on an earnest attempt.